# Creating a log to record when values change in a database

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to create a table which stores a date log of changes for certain attributes,easier to explain with an example + data - [DBFIDDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rFE8tVHkkb46qiBivPm8oE/2).

In the example I've created, I have a list of userids and if they're a fan of cheese. The log table is the one I want to use to record changes, and the current_table is the actual data source that gets refreshed every day.

Only 5 users have changed their preference which are:

1. 101
2. 102
3. 106
4. 107
5. 110

There are also two new userids which are:

1. 113
2. 114

A query would then run to check for new records in the current_day table or any changes compared against the latest entry in the log table. Any changes are inserted into the log table in an array format.

Based on the changed to the userids above as well as the new userids in the current_day table, the log table would then look something like the below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered merely using a [materialized view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-intro) that projects this information out from some larger table of all your logged changes? Because of how these views work, they'd automatically return fresh data whenever the underlying table changes and otherwise require no ongoing maintenance on your part. You're welcome to add `ORDER BY` to the view elements, but you can just as easily query the view and order that result.

I'd propose something along the lines of the following, to use your sample data:

```sql
WITH myData AS (
  select 
    userid, 
    likesCheese,
    lastUpdated
    FROM 
      UNNEST([
        STRUCT<userid int, likesCheese bool, lastUpdated DATE>(101, true, DATE(2022, 5, 19)),
        STRUCT<userid int, likesCheese bool, lastUpdated DATE>(101, false, DATE(2022, 5, 20)),
        STRUCT<userid int, likesCheese bool, lastUpdated DATE>(102, false, DATE(2022, 5, 19)),
        STRUCT<userid int, likesCheese bool, lastUpdated DATE>(102, true, DATE(2022, 5, 20)),
        STRUCT<userid int, likesCheese bool, lastUpdated DATE>(103, true, DATE(2022, 5, 19)),
        STRUCT<userid int, likesCheese bool, lastUpdated DATE>(104, true, DATE(2022, 5, 19)),
        STRUCT<userid int, likesCheese bool, lastUpdated DATE>(105, true, DATE(2022, 5, 19)),
        STRUCT<userid int, likesCheese bool, lastUpdated DATE>(106, false, DATE(2022, 5, 19)),
        STRUCT<userid int, likesCheese bool, lastUpdated DATE>(106, true, DATE(2022, 5, 20)),
        STRUCT<userid int, likesCheese bool, lastUpdated DATE>(107, true, DATE(2022, 5, 19)),
        STRUCT<userid int, likesCheese bool, lastUpdated DATE>(107, false, DATE(2022, 5, 20)),
        STRUCT<userid int, likesCheese bool, lastUpdated DATE>(108, true, DATE(2022, 5, 19)),
        STRUCT<userid int, likesCheese bool, lastUpdated DATE>(109, false, DATE(2022, 5, 19)),
        STRUCT<userid int, likesCheese bool, lastUpdated DATE>(110, true, DATE(2022, 5, 19)),
        STRUCT<userid int, likesCheese bool, lastUpdated DATE>(110, false, DATE(2022, 5, 20)),
        STRUCT<userid int, likesCheese bool, lastUpdated DATE>(111, false, DATE(2022, 5, 19)),
        STRUCT<userid int, likesCheese bool, lastUpdated DATE>(112, false, DATE(2022, 5, 19)),
        STRUCT<userid int, likesCheese bool, lastUpdated DATE>(113, true, DATE(2022, 5, 20)),
        STRUCT<userid int, likesCheese bool, lastUpdated DATE>(114, true, DATE(2022, 5, 20))
      ])
)
  SELECT
    userid,
    IF (likesCheese, 'YES', 'NO') as likesCheese,
    FORMAT_DATE("%d-%m-%Y", lastUpdated) as lastUpdated
  FROM myData
  ORDER BY userid ASC, lastUpdated ASC
```

This produces:

| userid | likesCheese | lastUpdated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | YES | 19-05-2022 |
| 101 | NO | 20-05-2022 |
| 102 | NO | 19-05-2022 |
| 102 | YES | 20-05-2022 |
| 103 | YES | 19-05-2022 |
| 104 | YES | 19-05-2022 |
| 105 | YES | 19-05-2022 |
| 106 | NO | 19-05-2022 |
| 106 | YES | 20-05-2022 |
| 107 | YES | 19-05-2022 |
| 107 | NO | 20-05-2022 |
| 108 | YES | 19-05-2022 |
| 109 | NO | 19-05-2022 |
| 110 | YES | 19-05-2022 |
| 110 | NO | 20-05-2022 |
| 111 | NO | 19-05-2022 |
| 112 | NO | 19-05-2022 |
| 113 | YES | 20-05-2022 |
| 114 | YES | 20-05-2022 |

If the formatting suits you, you'd go on to create a view from your table with the following:

```sql
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS `dataset.myview` (userid, likesCheese, lastUpdated) AS
  SELECT
    userid,
    IF (likesCheese, 'YES', 'NO') as likesCheese,
    FORMAT_DATE("%d-%m-%Y", lastUpdated) as lastUpdated
  FROM `yourSourceTable`
  ORDER BY userid ASC, lastUpdated ASC
```

And from there you'd go on to query the view just as you might any other table:

```sql
  SELECT
    userid,
    IF (likesCheese, 'YES', 'NO') as likesCheese,
    FORMAT_DATE("%d-%m-%Y", lastUpdated) as lastUpdated
  FROM `dataset.myview`
  ORDER BY userid ASC, lastUpdated ASC
```

And this would yield the same as above, but since it's coming from the view, anytime the underlying table is updated, it will be updated as well, but will cache those values in the interim leading to improved performance.